# Can GNU Parallel execute more parallel processes?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Can I for example execute:

`parallel -j 200 < list0`

Where "list" has:

`nice -n -20 parallel -j 100 < list2
nice -n -20 parallel -j 100 < list1`

Would this be feasible/possible?

Answer (score 0):

The number of processes is limited. In practice, don't run more than a few dozens of processes in parallel (at least on a personal computer; on million dollars machines the limit is definitely bigger).

Read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) man pages, to understand when and how they can fail.

And before reaching the limit where `fork` would fail, you'll reach a threshold where doing more parallel processes would *slow down* the entire computation, since the [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) inside the kernel will be overstressed.

If you have access to a network of computers (perhaps just two of them) consider also [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). If you can recode some of your applications read also about [pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthread) (e.g. [this tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/%E2%80%8E)).

Comment: Well parallel is executing a script that just uses a lopp to find a number, then download a file with ```wget``` using that number so I dont think there will be much of a problem if I push the -j param a bit, I could execute everything in a single parallel command but I want to have it in blocks so that in the case one dies the other is still working

Comment: You may think wrongly. Even if you are doing a lot of `wget`-s, you'll reach some limits quickly (e.g. network bandwidth). I don't think that running thousands of `wget` is wise.

Comment: I'm not even reaching 1MB/s on a 200MB/s network, CPU activity is at ~5% and I'm using ~60 ```wget```s right now

Comment: You probably have reached some bottleneck somewhere (perhaps on the network)

Comment: I have noticed slowdowns, here are some details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123823/why-does-parallel-slow-down-after-a-while

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do:

```
parallel -j0 < joblist
```

Then GNU Parallel will start as many jobs as it possibly can. It will typically be limited by either filehandles or processes.

If you cannot override the number of filehandles per process you can often cheat by:

```
parallel -j10 --pipe parallel -j0 < joblist
```

This will start 10 times as many jobs. This can also be used if the runtime of the jobs is in less than 10 ms (in which case the 2-3 ms overhead from GNU Parallel may be more than actually running the job).